# How to keep alive android webview with socket.io as long as application is open

Tags: android, socket.io, android-webview, activity-lifecycle

I have an android app which is using webview to load page which use socket.io - I would like to make that app alive as long as it's open to keep connection to socket's open.

Is there a way to avoid that Android will put app into background and cut connection ?

I have already tried to run Foreground service with separate socket.io connection but it did not helped.

it's similar issue to this one:
https://github.com/Red-Folder/bgs-core/issues/17

but I do not see an solution there

Comment: I think it is impossible, because WebView always should connect to Activity Context, and their lifecycles are strongly bounded.

Comment: I have to be possible because they have done it somehow using Cordova framework: https://github.com/BetterVoice/bv-bgs-foreground

but I dont know how to do it with regulard WebView

Comment: I advice you not use it, last update was 4 years ago.